# Plain image in R Markdown PDF output from function `scatter3d` and RGL

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, bookdown, rgl

I am creating a book with `bookdown` and I have run the `scatter3d()` function from `car` and `rgl`.

I have read that 3D images can be interactivelly implemented in HTML ([here](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/rgl_knitr.html)), however, what I need is to implement a simply plain image in the PDF output.

How can I do it?

Let's use this example:

```
scatter3d(mpg~hp+qsec|factor(cyl), data=mtcars, surface=FALSE, residuals=TRUE, 
  parallel=FALSE, bg="white", axis.scales=TRUE, grid=TRUE, ellipsoid=TRUE)
```

## EDIT 1

By employing @user2554330 's answer, I created an R Markdown file (.Rmd):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Mario"
date: "1 July 2019"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(rgl)
library(car)
setupKnitr()
```

Here's a plot:

```{r echo=TRUE, dev="png", rgl=TRUE}
scatter3d(mpg~hp+qsec|factor(cyl), data=mtcars, surface=FALSE, residuals=TRUE,
          parallel=FALSE, bg="white", axis.scales=TRUE, grid=TRUE, ellipsoid=TRUE)    
```
````

However, when I convert my .Rmd file to PDF, I do not see the plot:

[image]

Where's the problem?

Comment: Your document worked for me on MacOS, and showed the plot.  What system are you on?  What does `sessionInfo()` show?

Comment: It also worked for me when I tried it in Windows.  So I'm guessing the problem is something specific to your system.

Comment: I am using Linux Mint 19...

Comment: You probably haven't got the necessary libraries installed for rgl.  It needs "OpenGL, GLU Library, XQuartz (on OSX), zlib (optional), libpng (>=1.2.9, optional), FreeType (optional), pandoc (>=1.14, needed for vignettes)".  You appear to be missing FreeType and libpng.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can use `rgl.postscript()` to create a PDF file from an rgl image.  When it works, it will give the best quality, but it doesn't always work:  transparency isn't supported, etc.

`rgl.snapshot()` will generate a PNG image of the current rgl window.  That's likely to look a little pixellated unless you can make your rgl window really large.  (It would be nice to have virtual windows bigger than your screen, but rgl doesn't support non-screen buffers, and things like Xvfb tend not to support OpenGL drawing.)

Those are used by `knitr` hooks that `rgl` can install, so you can have a document like this:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
library(rgl)
library(car)
setupKnitr()
```

Here's a plot:

```{r rgl=TRUE, dev="png"}
scatter3d(mpg~hp+qsec|factor(cyl), data=mtcars, surface=FALSE, residuals=TRUE,
          parallel=FALSE, bg="white", axis.scales=TRUE, grid=TRUE, ellipsoid=TRUE)    
```
````

You can play with the chunk option `dpi` (dots per inch, default 72), but there will be an upper limit supported on your display.  You should be able to get bigger than the default unless you have a really large figure.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. It did not work properly. I edited my question with the results.